# GET() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, web.py, positional-argument

I am new to `web.py` and I tried making a simple application where I retrieve a HTML file and display it.

Here is my complete code:

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

When I run this, I get the error message:

> `<class 'TypeError'>` at /
>
> GET() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Whenever I add a random parameter to the GET function, the page is able to function, but otherwise not. It would be great if someone could point out what is going wrong here.

Comment: I dont't know what is web.py, but probably wsgi server passes request object as second argument into handler

Comment: According to the web.py docs, it is meant for python 2 and I downloaded the experimental version for python 3, could that possibly be a reason?

Comment: Ok, i got it. /(.*) means you want to capture one path parameter  and pass it into handler.

Comment: http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#urlhandling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(.*)` will be used as second argument, change your code

```
class index:
    def GET(self, name):
        return render.index(name)
```

and template `index.html`

```
$def with (name)
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello $name</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello $name
</body>
</html>
```

now try open `http://127.0.0.1:8080/John`